# Powershell not converting Foreach-Object parameter from string to integer even when provided [Int32] for type-casting

Tags: powershell, child-process, kill-process, powershell-5.1, one-liner

As mentioned in Question title, I have a Powershell one-liner for killing the Application/Process by Name and all it's relevant children processes:

```
powershell -c "Get-Process -Name `"Chrome`" | Select-Object -Property Id | ForEach-Object -Process { Stop-Process -Id $_.Id -Force }"
```

which when I tested by removing the process killing code and just printing IDs of processes, works just fine as below:

```
powershell -c "Get-Process -Name `"Chrome`" | Select-Object -Property Id"
```

This displays all IDs pertaining to Chrome instances as:

```
372
1232
1776
1884
2024
2676
3008
3240
```

But when I am trying to kill those processes with the first code block in this post, then it throws this error:

```
Stop-Process : Cannot bind parameter 'Id'. Cannot convert value ".Id" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

So I did applied [Int32] for type-conversion thinking that would be more than enough to bring the IDs into the Stop-Process part in valid format and kill it, but that also doesn't work:

```
powershell -c "Get-Process -Name `"Chrome`" | Select-Object -Property Id | ForEach-Object -Process { Stop-Process -Id [Int32]($_.Id) -Force }"
```

This throws error:

```
The term '.Id' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:108
+ ... y Id | ForEach-Object -Process { Stop-Process -Id [Int32](.Id) -Force ...
+                                                               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.Id:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can anyone help fix this and make the one-liner working by not too much elongating the one-liner ??

Comment: Something is removing the `$_` from `$_.id`. Is this part of a larger script or something?

Comment: No it's just this one-liner, independent, tried with Powershell, Powershell ISE, Windows Terminal and CMD not working anywhere with same error

Comment: mklement0's answer should resolve the issue, but is there a reason you don't just `powershell -c 'Get-Process -Name "Chrome" | Stop-Process -Force'`?

Comment: Yes from my little research I was thinking that maybe with this Chrome will be killed but only the main one, and the children will be orphaned but still alive, but I was wrong-assuming, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *immediate* fix: `$_.Id` -> `` `$_.Id ``

That is, you need to prevent *up-front* expansion of `$_` inside the [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) you're passing to the new child process, by escaping the `$` character as `` `$ `` in order to  retain it literally - just as you did with the embedded `"` characters (`` `" `` - though note that you don't strictly need to quote the `Chrome` argument at all).

Alternatively, given that your string doesn't actually require interpolation on the caller side, you can simply use a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), which also obviates the need to escape the embedded `$` and `"` chars.:

```sh
powershell -c 'Get-Process -Name "Chrome" | Select-Object -Property Id | ForEach-Object -Process { Stop-Process -Id $_.Id -Force }'
```

---

**Taking a step back:**

If you really need to **call another PowerShell instance - as an expensive child process - *from PowerShell***, you can **use a *script block***, which makes the escaping problems go away and also potentially returns - deserialized - *objects* rather than mere *string* output:

```sh
powershell -c { Get-Process -Name "Chrome" | Select-Object -Property Id | ForEach-Object -Process { Stop-Process -Id $_.Id -Force }
```

<sup>Note: If you needed to incorporate values from the *caller's* scope, you'd need to pass them to the child process via the `-Args` parameter; a simplified example: `powershell -c { Write-Output "$args!" } -Args hi`</sup>

---

As for **shortening the command itself**:

```sh
powershell -c { Get-Process Chrome | Stop-Process -Force }
```

The above takes advantage of `-Name` being implied as the target parameter of the first *positionally* passed argument, as well as `Stop-Process` ability to directly operate on process-info objects received via the pipeline, as output by `Get-Process`.